# dojo1.10 Dynamic update of dijit.form.Select

Tags: dojo

I was trying to asynchronously update a Select field via Memory and ObjectStore. This doesn't work. Setting the data to the Memory object before creating the Select element works fine. Updating the Memory object after creating the Select element doesn't work anymore.

Example code:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",

    "dijit/form/Select",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/store/Observable",
    "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
    'dojo/domReady!'
    ], function(ready, Select, Memory, Observable, ObjectStore, dom){
        ready(function() {
                var mymem = new Memory();
                var myobs = new Observable(mymem);
                var mystore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: myobs });

                /* updating memory here works :) */
                //mymem.setData([ { id: 2, label: 'qwertz2' }, { id: 3, label: 'qwertz3' } ]);

                var s = new Select({
                    store: mystore
                }, 'appsAdminQueueContainer');
                s.startup();

                /* updating memory here doesn't work :( */
                mymem.setData([ { id: 2, label: 'qwertz2' }, { id: 3, label: 'qwertz3' } ]);
        });
    }
);
```

Real working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mirQ/ra0dqb63/5/

Is this a bug or is there a solution to be able to update the content of the Select field after creating it - without having to access the Select field directly?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your response.

- The use of `dojo/ready` was just a missed leftover while simplifying my code, sorry.
- That the use of the `ObjectStore` is not necessary was not clear to me. Thanks for clearing up.
- Okay, the real problem seems to be indeed the last point. I think I have to extend my description.

*Updated/extended problem description:*

I'm using a grid. At first I was using `dojox/grid/DataGrid`, but then I switched to `dgrid`. Everything works well, but I want to use `dijit.form.Select` as editor for one column. This works also well if the data is static. But in one column I have to read dynamic data from the server. This data comes in JSON format.

First I tried to solve this with the use of `dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore` - that worked. But it's deprecated and I need to implement a formatter for that column that has to have access to the same JSON data read from the server. I don't have the code for that solution anymore, but it didn't work. I wasn't able to successfully query the data from within the formatter function.

Then I switched to `Memory` and `xhr`. The response from the server comes after the Memory object is created (and, as it seems, after creating the Select), so I had to use `setData` to bring my loaded data in the store. And because the Select is only an editor of a grid, I don't have access to the object itself to be able to re-set the store after updating the data.

I hope my extended description makes my real problem a bit clearer. Thanks in advance for your help!

Mirko

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
require([
    'dijit/form/Select',
    'dojo/store/Memory',
    'dojo/store/Observable',
], function (Select, Memory, Observable) {
    var mymem = new Memory({
        data: [{
            id: 2,
            label: 'qwertz2'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            label: 'qwertz3'
        }]
    });

    var myobs = new Observable(mymem);

    var s = new Select({
        labelAttr: 'label',
        store: myobs
    }, 'appsAdminQueueContainer');
    s.startup();

    myobs.add({ id: 4, label: 'qwerty' });
});
```

Notable changes:

- There's no reason to use `dojo/ready` in this code. The `require` callback already waits for modules to load, and as long as this script is at the bottom of the body, there's no need to wait for the DOM to load, either.
- There's no need to use a `dojo/data` store adapter.  `dijit/form/Select` supports `dojo/store` as well (as of 1.8 if I recall correctly).  This might also have been why observation wasn't working.  The only difference is `labelAttr` must be specified on the `Select` since `dojo/store` has no concept of a label property.
- (Edit) now that I re-read the question, I notice you are calling `setData`.  `setData` does not fire observers.  `setData` completely resets the store's data, and to reflect that, you would need to actually reset the store on the select entirely (which requires calling `setStore`, not `set('store', ...)`, if you are using 1.9 or earlier, because Select was never updated properly to support the `set` API until 1.10).
- (Edit #2) Given that the primary reason you are calling `setData` is due to creating the store before actually having data for it, your case would probably be greatly simplified by using the `RequestMemory` store implementation from [dojo-smore](https://github.com/kfranqueiro/dojo-smore/blob/master/RequestMemory.js).  It basically re-adds the `url` support that `dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore` had but `dojo/store/Memory` didn't.